# How to print out the GCD in different format

Tags: java, printing, while-loop, greatest-common-divisor

I am trying to ask the user to enter two integers and have the message to say
"The GCD of "first integer" and "second integer" is "GCD"

I have all my calculations right but it is just printing out my num1 for all values.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Assignment3
{

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the first integer: ");
        int num1 = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the second integer: ");
        int num2 = scan.nextInt();

        while (num1 != num2)
        {
            if (num1> num2)
            num1 = num1 - num2;
            else
            num2 = num2 - num1;


            }


        System.out.println("The gcd of" + num1 + " and " + num2 + " is " + num1);

    }


}
```

Comment: _"but it is just printing out my num1 for all values"_ Why wouldn't it? You modify `num1` and `num2` in the loop, and the exit condition for your loop is that `num1` equals `num2`. If you want to print the original values of `num1` and `num2` then print them before the loop, or save copies of them that can be printed later on.

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop you check if num1 != num2 so when the println gets executed num1 will have the same value as num2.